# vsftpd - trim password for white space

Tags: ftp

Is there anyway to set the password to be automatically trimmed on space at start/end when logging in via FTP?

I have found that a lot of my clients are having problems when copy/pasting the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSFTPd is free software (licensed under [GPL v2](ftp://vsftpd.beasts.org/users/cevans/untar/vsftpd-3.0.0/LICENSE)), so you can get the source and edit it yourself, to make the password-checking code white-space insensitive.  Other than that, no, I'm not ware of any magic option to do that.

Comment: If I remember well, vsftp never see the passwords: they are only managed by PAM

Comment: I'm not sure that is right; vsftpd's the code that's running, talking to the user.  It may well invoke PAM to validate the credentials it collects, but it still has to collect them.

Comment: You're right. vfsftp directly talk to the user, THEN deal with PAM. So the password can be filtered by vsftp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PAM module to filter user/password.
Either you find a module alerady available, either you have to build your own. Have a look at http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_ADG.html for building.

The PAM configuration for vsftp is into `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd`

Edit: I remember about `pam_script.so`
This PAM module allow you to run arbitrary command from PAM. So no need to develop something in C. Just use Bash to filter the password.
Similar need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284624/hook-into-linux-authentication-to-run-script-or-program-when-certain-conditions